# write a batch file to run a program, and rename inputs and outputs for each loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have 100 ASCII text files, named as
file1.sit
file2.sit
...
file100.sit

Now, I am running a program called program.EXE, using file.sit as an input, and output a file called file.out

So, Now I am writing a batch program to do the following for 100 loops:

1. For each loop, first rename file*.sit to file.sit
2. run program.exe
3. rename the output from file.out to file*.out
4. delete file.sit, so that in next loop, a new file.sit can be placed there.

ultimately, the output list should be like:

file1.out
file2.out
...
file100.out

I have started with some code like this. But with limited knowledge on batch file, I don't know how to proceed. Anyone can help?

Thanks

```
@echo off

 for %%f in (*.SIT) do (

            echo %%~nf
            Rename %%f file.SIT
pause
        program.EXE
        Rename file.out *.out
        Del file.sit
    )

pause
```

Comment: use `for /L` to generate the numbers

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: I guess I understand your points. Will try it tomorrow on the working computer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You were very much on the right track. This just "fills in" your code.

I guess you know you only need to count the number of loops if you have more than 100 files named file(number).sit. If you do, you can add a counter and check it with an IF statement each loop and stop after 100 ([see here](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)).

Here, the dir command loops through all files matching "file*.sit" in the directory and as you planned, the ~n strips the extension when the loop starts. A variable is set for the name without extension (personal preference), which is used to rename your output file.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    :: Per dir /b, this works on current directory.
    For /f %%G in ('dir /b "file*.sit"') do (
        :: Store filename (no extention) in "thisfile" var
        set thisfile=%%~nG

        :: To update variables inside the loop use !marks
        Rename "!thisfile!.sit" file.SIT
        pause

        :: If program doesn't run, use: Start "" "program.EXE" 
        program.EXE
        :: Rename and delete
        Rename file.out "!thisfile!.out"
        Del file.sit
    )
    pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your `ren` into `copy` and `del` to avoid possible loss of input files. Appart from this, you had it almost coded. Your fail was not to use the `%%~nf` in the output file rename

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    del file.sit >nul 2>nul
    for %%a in (*.sit) do (
        copy /y %%a file.sit
        program.exe
        ren file.out %%~na.out
        del file.sit >nul 2>nul
    )
```

If input files should be discarded (as it seems from your code), then change `copy` with  `move`